# Multiple instances of the trigger running at the same time

Tags: apex, trigger

I have the a trigger firing when a CPQ Subscription record has its Status updated to a value of 'Not Renewed' and its related Renewal Opportunity is still open (based on its Stage).  The trigger is then checking to see if there are any other 'Active' Subscriptions relating to the same Contract record.

If there aren't any other Active Subscriptions on that Contract, the trigger is setting the related renewal opportunity to a Stage of 'Closed Lost'.  This is all working as expected when I manually update a subscription record within the UI.  It's also working as expected when I batch update Subscriptions to 'Not Renewed' via list views or the dataloader.

An issue I'm having is when I test the following scenario: Updating two subscriptions from the same Contract to a status of 'Not Renewed' at the same time.  If I have two subscription records open within two separate tabs, and update them both to 'Not Renewed' at the same time.

If I manage to save the two records in a short enough time span of each other, then their related 'Open' renewal opportunity is not updating to 'Closed Lost'.  After debugging the Subscription query in the controller class, it looks like even in the second transaction, the query is still seeing the subscription from the first transaction as being marked with an 'Active' Status.

I'm just not sure exactly why since the trigger context is set to run after update.  I would think by the second transaction, the Subscription query in the controller should see the first transaction's Subscription record now have a Status of 'Not Renewed'.  Am I missing something?

Trigger:

```
    trigger CPQ_Subscription_Trigger on SBQQ__Subscription__c (after update, after insert, before update, before insert) {
       
        if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate){
            Set<Id> notRenewSubIds = new Set<Id>();
            Set<Id> contractIdSet = new Set<Id>();
                
            if(Trigger.oldmap.get(sub.id).Status__c != Trigger.newmap.get(sub.id).Status__c && 
                Trigger.newmap.get(sub.id).Status__c == 'Not Renewed' && sub.SBQQ__Contract__r.SBQQ__RenewalOpportunity__r.StageName != 'Closed Won' && sub.SBQQ__Contract__r.SBQQ__RenewalOpportunity__r.StageName != 'Closed List'){
                        
                        contractIdSet.add(sub.SBQQ__Contract__c);
                        notRenewSubIds.add(sub.Id);
                } 
                
                if(contractIdSet.size() > 0){
                    CPQ_Subscription_Trigger_Helper.updateRenewalOpportunity(contractIdSet, notRenewSubIds);
                }
        }
}
```

Controller class:

```
public with sharing class CPQ_Subscription_Trigger_Helper {
    public static void updateRenewalOpportunity(Set<Id> contractIdSet, Set<Id> subIdSet) {

        List<SBQQ__Subscription__c> relatedSubs = new List<SBQQ__Subscription__c>([SELECT Id, Status__c, SBQQ__Contract__c, SBQQ__Contract__r.SBQQ__RenewalOpportunity__c FROM SBQQ__Subscription__c WHERE Status__c = 'Active' AND Id NOT IN: subIdSet AND SBQQ__Contract__c IN : contractIdSet]);

        Set<Id> activeContractIdList = new Set<Id>();
        for(SBQQ__Subscription__c sub : relatedSubs) {
            activeContractIdList.add(sub.SBQQ__Contract__c);
        }

        contractIdSet.removeAll(activeContractIdList);

        List<Opportunity> renewalOppList = new List<Opportunity>();
        for(Opportunity opp : [SELECT Id, StageName FROM Opportunity WHERE SBQQ__RenewedContract__c IN : contractIdSet FOR UPDATE]) {
            opp.StageName = 'Closed Lost';
            opp.Closed_Lost_Reason__c = 'Not Renewed';
            renewalOppList.add(opp);
        }
        update renewalOppList;
    }
}
```

Comment: _I would think by the second transaction, the Subscription query in the controller should see the first transaction's Subscription record now have a Status of 'Not Renewed'_ : not necessarily, the outcome depends on whether the 1st transaction committed its results by the time the 2nd transaction kicked off. As you have found out, this is timing-dependent. A solution architecture that expects things to work based on timing is a poor one. In your case it's unclear whether you're simply stress testing by going above and beyond or it's truly an issue for the business.

Comment: If a real issue, then you'll need to redesign and explicitly sequence these transactions.

Comment: Thanks @identigral.  I do believe I'm stress testing a scenario that most likely would not happen, but we know how that goes... Anyways, thanks for your comments - I think I'm going to consider using something async/scheduled to update the opps at a later time.